# How can I change my output so the grades are behind the names?

Tags: python, python-3.x

first of all I'm a complete programming noob but I had to do this small assignment for school to pass so it would really help me out if someone could give me the last answer to my question. (BTW I'M USING THE LATEST PYTHON)

So I will summarise the assignment: I received an .txt file with a list of 10 students, after every students name there are 3 grades (the lowest grade can be a 1 and the highest grade a 10).

Small example of how the list looks:

Tom Bombadil__________6.5 5.5 4.5

Dain IJzervoet________6.7 7.2 7.7

Thorin Eikenschild____6.8 7.8 7.3

Now I need to type a code that will exactly give this output when I run the program:

```
Report for group 2b

Tom Bombadil has an average grade of 5.5

Dain IJzervoet has an average grade of 7.2

Thorin Eikenschild has an average grade of 7.3

Meriadoc Brandebok has an average grade of 4.6

Sam Gewissies has an average grade of 4.5

Gollem has an average grade of 1.8

Frodo Ballings has an average grade of 6.8

Gandalf de Grijze has an average grade of 9.5

Peregrijn Toek has an average grade of 6.2

Radagast de Bruine has an average grade of 8.8

End of report
```

This is my code now:

```
NUMBER_OF_GRADES = 3

def print_geo_grades(input_grades):
    all_grades = list(map(float, input_grades.split(" ")))

    first_grade = all_grades[0]
    second_grade = all_grades[1]
    third_grade = all_grades[2]

    average_grade = (first_grade + second_grade + third_grade) / NUMBER_OF_GRADES

    print("%.1f" % average_grade)

def print_student(all_students):
    student_details = all_students.split("_")

    full_name_student = student_details[0]
    all_grades = student_details[-1]

    print("%s has an average grade of " % full_name_student, print_geo_grades(all_grades))

'''Start Program'''
print("Report for group 2b")
students = open('geo_grades1.in.txt').readlines()

for each_student in students:
    print_student(each_student)

print("End of report")
```

And this is the output it now gives me:

```
Report for group 2b
5.5
Tom Bombadil has an average grade of  None
7.2
Dain IJzervoet has an average grade of  None
7.3
Thorin Eikenschild has an average grade of  None
4.6
Meriadoc Brandebok has an average grade of  None
4.5
Sam Gewissies has an average grade of  None
1.8
Gollem has an average grade of  None
6.8
Frodo Ballings has an average grade of  None
9.5
Gandalf de Grijze has an average grade of  None
6.2
Peregrijn Toek has an average grade of  None
8.8
Radagast de Bruine has an average grade of  None
End of report

Process finished with exit code 0
```

As you can see are the average grades in front of the names and where the averages should be it says 'None'. Please guys I'm almost there and I need to finish this before friday 23:59. PLEASE HELP A BROTHER OUT!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the grade from the function `print_geo_grades` instead of printing it. Just add return and remove print from the function and it should work:

```
def print_geo_grades(input_grades):
    all_grades = list(map(float, input_grades.split(" ")))

    first_grade = all_grades[0]
    second_grade = all_grades[1]
    third_grade = all_grades[2]

    average_grade = (first_grade + second_grade + third_grade) / NUMBER_OF_GRADES

    return round(average_grade,1)
```

Comment: David this actually worked, but the only problem now is it doesn't round the average grade to one decimal place. Can I put the %.1f back behind that line? (Btw thank you so much for the answer I was really struggling.

Comment: @Atmtje You just want to specify the `%.1f` again: `print("%s has an average grade of %.1f" %(full_name_student, print_geo_grades(all_grades)))`.

Comment: @Atmtje It's in the same spot as before.

Comment: @Guimoute i'm probably gonna be annoying but can you please show me which part trough copy and pasting it here because I tried every place but it doesn't work for me :'(.

Comment: You are welcome! You can do as @Guimoute suggested or also use the python function `round` (see updated answer).

Comment: @Atmtje the code that Guimoute suggested goes inside `print_student` function, just replace the last line (the print) in that function with the code in Guimoute's comment.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to return your  `average_grade`, just add a,

`return average_grade` statement to your function such as,

```
def print_geo_grades(input_grades):
    all_grades = list(map(float, input_grades.split(" ")))

    first_grade = all_grades[0]
    second_grade = all_grades[1]
    third_grade = all_grades[2]

    average_grade = (first_grade + second_grade + third_grade) / NUMBER_OF_GRADES

    return average_grade
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank you so much brother for the help, it's really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The function you are calling doesn't return any value.
you can fix this in two ways

1. instead of printing just `return average_grade`
2. call `print_geo_grades()` outside the print statement

   **use any one.**

The string formating you are using in print statement is really old fashioned, instead refer the code below

```
    NUMBER_OF_GRADES = 3

def print_geo_grades(input_grades):
    all_grades = list(map(float, input_grades.split(" ")))

    first_grade = all_grades[0]
    second_grade = all_grades[1]
    third_grade = all_grades[2]

    average_grade = (first_grade + second_grade + third_grade) / NUMBER_OF_GRADES
#just return python will not consider the zeroes after decimal
    return average_grade                                                                                        

def print_student(all_students):
    student_details = all_students.split("_")

    full_name_student = student_details[0]
    all_grades = student_details[-1]
 #new way of writing
    print("{} has an average grade of {}".format(full_name_student, print_geo_grades(all_grades)))             

'''Start Program'''
print("Report for group 2b")
students = open('geo_grades1.in.txt').readlines()
for each_student in students:
    print_student(each_student)

print("End of report")



>Report for group 2b
>Tom Bombadil has an average grade of 5.5
>Dain IJzervoet has an average grade of 7.2
>Thorin Eikenschild has an average grade of 7.3
>End of report
```

Comment: I find that old-fashioned string formatting and f-strings are both superior to `"{}".format(...)` which looks bloaty.

Comment: Yes the return helped indeed, but it doesn't round the grades now to one decimal place. Anyway I could fix that?

Comment: Python does the rounding automatically.

Comment: actually using the f-strings will soon be deprecated. when you'll be using the python in actual practice you will have to use format and also gonna understand what .format has to offer

Comment: Alright brother, thank you so much for the help. Only thing is it didn't round the grades for me in the output very weird. I actually took over your code and replaced it with my part but it still didn't round the grades.

Comment: @NikhilGhule Come on, f-strings are getting even better in 3.8 and Python does not round numbers automatically...

Comment: When Im using python since 2 years now, i don't which version are you using but im on 3.8.0 and i just edited my answer and added the output i got

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the simplest solution is:

```
import re
from statistics import mean


with open("marks.txt") as fd:
    for line in fd:
        name, raw_marks = re.split(r"_+", line)
        marks = map(float, raw_marks.split())
        print(f"{name} has average grade {mean(marks)}")
```

Comment: Let's not throw two modules at someone who is still learning prints. `split(" ")` and `split("_")` are just fine here.